# Append to an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, parallel-processing

I am trying to use the parallel gem in ruby to call a function on each element of an array

```
require 'parallel'

arr = %w[one two three four five]
result ||= []    
Parallel.each(arr) do |elem|
  result << Random.rand(10)
end
```

But, when I run this, the result array is always empty. Why does it not append?
It behaves the same way when `result` is a ruby `Queue`

Comment: `arr` is an array `%w[one two three four five]`. Editing the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass in a `:in_threads` option:

```
require 'parallel'

arr = %w[one two three four five]
result ||= []
Parallel.each(arr, :in_threads => 8) do |elem|
  result << Random.rand(10)
end
```

Don't ask me to explain this in detail; I was just looking through the source code for the Parallel project and saw this as a possibility and tried it.

My guess is that it tells the threads to run as threads so that that they can share the `result` variable, rather than running as separate processes. But that's just a guess.

Comment: I ended up using this one, with `:in_threads` set to the `arr.count`

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't append b/c `Parallel` forks into subprocesses that no longer share the same reference to `result`. In this case, one option might be to use `Parallel.map` and append the resulting array to `result`, ie

```
result ||= []    
result += Parallel.map(arr) { |elem| Random.rand(10) }
```

Answer (score 1):

Each `<<` operation happens in its own separate process (ie. in parallel) and so it's mutating a different `result` variable.

This happens because `Parallel` [forks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28system_call%29) processes and forked processes have their own memory.